# Update a specific nested component without interefering with other ones (parents)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to be able to update a nested component properties without updating the other ones.

The use case is quite simple to understand:

I have a Table (component), that contains Players (a Player is a component), that contains Cards (a Card is a componant).

So i have something like:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        </ Player>
        </ Player>
        </ Player>
        </ Player>
        </ Player>
        </ Player>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Player = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="player">
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Card = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
       <span>{this.props.rank}</span>
       <span>{this.props.color}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Table, null),
  document.getElementById('table')
);
```

So what i am wondering is, how can i change the properties of a certain player's cards ?

For example, how could i assign the cards { rank: 1, color: 0 } and { rank: 2, color: 0 } to the player 3 ?

Do i have a upate the whole Table (so every players and cards) everytime i want to update something ? Or is there a way to update a specific "nested component" ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind React is that you update the complete table: all players and all cards. React takes care of incremental updates: it leaves all unchanged players and cards alone, and updates only card set of the specific player.

This makes it easy to code and debug, and let react worry about updates and performance.

You could take care of updating the set of one player yourself. By giving each player component state, and by defining your own functions to get the current card set for player x in the player's component, by adding listeners to make sure player component is informed of updates to his own card set, etc.